# To .append to a specific html tag .each search jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hope I can be helped. I have this html code:

```
<div class="resource_listing">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Categories</h3>   
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Boxed Style</a></li>              
      <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
         <ul class=" innerList">
           <li class="current"><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Material</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
     <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to add a "right angle font awesome icon" on the 'li' tag that has a child. Here is my Jquery script

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.resource_listing li').each(function() {
        if($(this).children('ul').length > 0 ){
        $(this).append( '<span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>' );
        }
    }); 
});
```

Now the thing is, it appends the font awesome icon just before the closing tag of 'li' ( but I want the script to append between the 'a' tags. That is, after the script runs I want the icon added like this

```
<li><a href="#">Dropdown 
      <span class="indicator">
         <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
     <ul class=" innerList">
       <li class="current"><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Material</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: just change `$(this).append(..` to `$(this).find('a:first').append(..` or `$(this).children('a').append(..` (ie. append the icon to the first anchor)

Comment: Thank you!! Absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `a` tag within the list item and append the indicator to it using [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```js
$('.resource_listing li').each(function() {
  // check the nested ul count
  if ($('ul', this).length) {
    // get the first `a` tag within and append the content
    $('a:first', this).append('<span class="indicator"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resource_listing">
  <h3 class="widget-title">Categories</h3> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Boxed Style</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Video</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class=" innerList">
        <li class="current"><a href="#">Audio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Material</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Video</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked as a charm! Now that I am still learning Jquery and JS, will come here, 1st thing, for help.